# Action route not available from URL. What do I have wrong?

Tags: controller, cron

I built a plugin for Craft 3 and need to run one of its actions via CRON. I know I can set this up as a console command, and will do that, but before I get there, I'd like to solve this issue.

I noticed my CRON was failing, and when I attempted to run the URL myself, at `http://campaigns.gcx.loc/actions/gcxCampaignTools/stats/syncCampaignsRemote`, I got this error:

```
yii\base\InvalidRouteException: Unable to resolve the request "gcxCampaignTools/stats/syncCampaignsLocal". in /Users/Chad/Sites/gcx-campaigns/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Module.php:537
Stack trace:
#0 /Users/Chad/Sites/gcx-campaigns/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Application.php(299): yii\base\Module->runAction('gcxCampaignTool...', Array)
#1 /Users/Chad/Sites/gcx-campaigns/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Application.php(566): craft\web\Application->runAction('gcxCampaignTool...', Array)
#2 /Users/Chad/Sites/gcx-campaigns/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Application.php(278): craft\web\Application->_processActionRequest(Object(craft\web\Request))
#3 /Users/Chad/Sites/gcx-campaigns/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(386): craft\web\Application->handleRequest(Object(craft\web\Request))
#4 /Users/Chad/Sites/gcx-campaigns/public_html/index.php(21): yii\base\Application->run()
#5 {main}

Next yii\web\NotFoundHttpException: Page not found. in /Users/Chad/Sites/gcx-campaigns/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Application.php:570
Stack trace:
#0 /Users/Chad/Sites/gcx-campaigns/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Application.php(278): craft\web\Application->_processActionRequest(Object(craft\web\Request))
#1 /Users/Chad/Sites/gcx-campaigns/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(386): craft\web\Application->handleRequest(Object(craft\web\Request))
#2 /Users/Chad/Sites/gcx-campaigns/public_html/index.php(21): yii\base\Application->run()
#3 {main}
```

The action works from a front end link with the following code when I am logged in (user must be logged in to use the entire app, so login is required to run the action as well):

`<a href="/actions/gcx-campaign-tools/stats/sync-campaigns-local">Sync Campaigns</a>`

Because it worked when logged in, I thought I may need to allow anonymous in the controller, but that was already in place. I tried both `protected $allowAnonymous = true;` and `protected $allowAnonymous = ['actionSyncCampaignsRemote'];` with the same results.

Here is a screenshot of my plugin file structure and controller actions: [screenshot](https://d.pr/i/2ByGtW)

As you can see there I did put `URL: /actions/gcx-campaign-tools/stats/sync-campaigns-remote` in the code comments when I built this. Loading that URL produces the same error.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Can you try
`protected $allowAnonymous = ['sync-campaigns-remote']; `

Answer (score 2):

Turns out the controller action was running, but since I was just using `return`, Craft was looking for a template to show once the functions were complete, and failing when it didn't find one. Using `die();` after the function runs is working fine.